# How to add object inside object in php?

Tags: php, json

I am currently having problem creating a json response as I don't use PHP that much but can anyone help me create json like below:

```
{
  "set_attributes": 
    {
      "apikey": "some value",
    },
  "block_names": ["getdata"],
  "type": "show_block",
  "title": "go"
}
```

Here's my code:

```
    $response = array();
    $response['block_names'] = array();
    $response['block_names'] = "getdata";
    $response['type'] = "show_block";
    $response['title'] = "go";

    if ($db->studentLogin($username, $password)) {
        $student = $db->getStudent($username);
        $temp = array();
        $temp['apikey'] = $student['api_key'];
        $response['set_attributes'] = $temp['apikey'];
    } else {
        $temp = array();
        $response['messages'] = array();
        $temp['text'] = "Invalid username or password";
        array_push($response['messages'],$temp);
    }
    echoResponse(200, $response);
```

It shows like this:

```
{
  "block_names": "getdata",
  "type": "show_block",
  "title": "go",
  "set_attributes": "f74911b29778adea86aa24d5ce85ff58"
}
```

But I want to add apikey = "f74911b29778adea86aa24d5ce85ff58" inside set_attributes and [] outside block_names just like obove. how can I do that?

Comment: `$response['set_attributes'] = $temp;` - Now you take just value

Comment: `$response['block_names'] = array("getdata");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
$response['block_names'] = array("getdata");
...
$response['set_attributes'] = new \stdClass();
$response['set_attributes']->apikey = 'some_api_key';
```

https://3v4l.org/GDMKT#output